# Evaluate $ \ \int_C \vec F \cdot d \vec s \ $

Tags: calculus

Let $ \ \vec F(x,y)=xy^2 \hat i+x^2y \hat j \ $ . Evaluate $ \ \int_C \vec F \cdot d \vec s \ $ , where $ \ C \ $ is the **upper half** of the circle $ \ x^2+y^2=1 \ $

**Answer:**

Let,

$ x=\cos(t) , \\ y=\sin(t) \ $

$ d \vec s=dx \hat i+ dy \hat j= -\sin (t) dt \hat i+\cos (t) dt \hat j \ $

Thus,

$ \vec F \cdot d \vec ds =-\frac{1}{4} \sin (4t ) \ $

Therefore,

$ \int_C \vec F \cdot d \vec s=-\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin (4t) dt \ =0 \ $

**Am I right ?**

**Help me out**

Comment: Maybe that the minus sign is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
\vec F \cdot \vec ds=\cos t \sin^2 t (-\sin t)dt + \cos^2 t\sin t(\cos t) dt=$$ 
$$= \sin t \cos t(\cos^2 t-\sin^2 t)dt= 
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\sin (2t) \cos(2t)=\frac{1}{4}\sin(4t)
$$

So there is a sign error in your result, but it does not matter for the final result.